# Macbook Pro 15.4" Aluminum body alternative to Magsafe Charger

Tags: macbook, charging, magsafe

Is there any other method of charging this Macbook Pro late 2009 other than the Magsafe. Mine broke, I have a magsafe coming and need to use my system but is low on battery now. Can you charge through a USB port directly to an electrical outlet?

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is indeed to **wait for your new charger** (or to visit the Apple Store and plugin there while you "shop". I've done that during power pinches.

You *could* make your own charging setup. This document contains the [pinout of MagSafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagSafe). Suffice to say, you'd need to produce 16.5VDC with something and get it on to those pins safely. You'll probably need to be able to push up to 90W too. You would want to recycle your previous (presumably damaged) power brick to get the connector.

**Just go to a store and hijack enough power to tie you over.**

Comment: "Borrowing" power: +1

Answer (score 1):

**No.** You can't charge a MacBook without a MagSafe connector. Not without major efforts and soldering skills I guess.

MagSafe is the only way to power a MacBook if they're not running on battery alone. If your connector broke, you're out of luck.

There are/were third party replacements for hooking an external power source to a Mac (given a working MagSafe connector on your Mac), but Apple owns the patent and does not license the connector.